# How to modify SessionHandler::gc $maxlifetime?

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection

Is there a way of modifying the $maxlifetime for `SessionHandler::gc ( int $maxlifetime )` ?

I want to be able to check if the session is admin session or frontend session.

If it's admin session then the `$maxlifetime = 15 minutes` and frontend session to be `$maxlifetime = 1 hour`. Can the `$maxtimelife` be edited like that?

```
public function gc($maxlifetime) {
    foreach (glob("$this->savePath/sess_*") as $file) {
        if (filemtime($file) + $maxlifetime < time() && file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
            // Check if it's admin session....(as this should happen after 15 mins).... 
            // Remove Auth_Key
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```